# Does subtle body goes into the next birth?

Tags: vedanta, rebirth, body

I'm studying Yoga from an Acharya and he taught us that its the causal body which is resposible for getting the next birth.

But I also heard somewhere else that its the subtle body which leaves the physical body at time of death. Which one is true?

Does subtle body goes into the next birth or a new subtle body is created by causual body at the time of death?

UPDATE -

This ([Does the subtle body carry the prana airs after the death of the physical vessel?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31691/does-the-subtle-body-carry-the-prana-airs-after-the-death-of-the-physical-vessel)) doesn't answer my question because it doesn't say if subtle body is reused in the next birth or a new one is created which is my question.

This answer ([What actually transfers during rebirth?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36475/what-actually-transfers-during-rebirth)) suggests that subtle body transmigrates during death but my Acharya says that its only the impressions (samskaras) which transmigrates. The buddhi, manas and memory doesn't travel, therefore its wrong to conclude that subtle body lives after death. He says that causal body creates a new subtle body after death.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the subtle body carry the prana airs after the death of the physical vessel?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31691/does-the-subtle-body-carry-the-prana-airs-after-the-death-of-the-physical-vessel)

Comment: No. It's not clear. That answer hasn't mentioned if subtle body is reused in next birth or a new one is created which is my question here.

Comment: Maybe, You can add that question in this question then, and explain this there that it's not a duplicate of that question?! In that way, this won't be closed.

Comment: @Vivikta Good idea. Thank you.

Comment: @hanugm Yes that answers the question but I still have a doubt. Let me update the question.

Comment: @Lokesh Okay.......

Comment: **The buddhi, manas, and memory don't travel** it is wrong. Please read [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28842/when-does-a-soul-lose-its-memory-of-its-previous-birth)

Comment: Does that mean if a person becomes animal in next brith, he will retain the same mind, buddhi and memory?

Comment: Is by your Acharya you meant your own spiritual Guru? @Lokesh

Comment: No. He teaches us about Yoga in an University.

Comment: Okay but your comment did not notify me as you have not put at my username @Lokesh

Comment: @Lokesh Please read the answers, she forgets as soon as she comes out of the womb.

Comment: @hanugm First answer says that a child remembers till he becomes 9 months old.