# What supernatural things have happened in Hinduism?

Tags: history, supernatural

What miracles or other supernatural concepts have happened in Hinduism?

Comment: most incidents in Ramayana and Mahabharata are considered supernatural by today's standards

Comment: @ram if you don’t mind posting it as an answer it would be appreciated

Comment: **OPINION based** Supernatural is a subjective term. The thing is everything is natural. The only thing supernatural is God (Brahman) himself. Everything else is Prakriti (Nature)/Purusha and there is nothing beyond Prakriti or Maya except God. In the context you’re asking, what might be considered as supernatural by some may not be considered supernatural by others for example the existence of Preta who’s shraddha karma has not been done. Thus, in my opinion, the answer may result in being **opinion based**

Comment: @Archit how do you know if you are avatar if there are no miracles

Comment: I am not anyone’s avatar :)

Comment: you are walking upright, whereas all vertiberate walk horizontal.. that is micrale that is happening in hinduism.. that is super naturl thing. .You are speaking that is supernatural.. because no other living entity other than human speak.. like that every thing is happening on its own in your body that is supernatural . if you closely observe nature every leaf of tree is different that is supernatural and every thumb print of human is unique is that not supernatural.. who made all this possible.. God.. this was told by bheesma.. in anusanaparva of mahabharata..

Comment: hindusim explains all things supernatural by one thing that is God.

Comment: The channeling of the Vimanika Shastra is pretty supernatural.

Comment: Define supernatural and miracle. Usually they are intimately associated with a different religion.

Comment: What do you define as supernatural? Hanuman has all siddhis and he and Ram have supernatural weapons.

Comment: @Wikash_ like the biblical basis of miracles.  water parting.  Snake to stick and other miracles.

Comment: Well my answer remains the same in that case.

Answer (score 6):

I am posting passages describing Swami Vivekananda's supernatural experiences with Sri Ramakrishna (who is regarded as an Avatar by millions).

> In a state of mental conflict and torture of soul, Narendra (Swami
> Vivekananda) came to Sri Ramakrishna (Sri RK) at Dakshineswar. He was
> then eighteen years of age and had been in college two years. He
> entered the Master's room accompanied by some light-hearted friends.
> At Sri RK's request he sang a few songs, pouring his whole soul into
> them, and the Master went into Samadhi. A few moments later Sri RK
> suddenly left his seat, took Narendra by the hand, and led him to the
> screened verandah north of his room. They were alone. Addressing
> Narendra most tenderly, as if he were a friend of long acquaintance,
> the Master said: "Ah! You have come very late. Why have you been so
> unkind as to make me wait all these days? My ears are tired of hearing
> the futile words of worldly men. Oh, how I have longed to pour my
> spirit into the heart of someone fitted to receive my message!" ..
> Then, standing before Narendra with folded hands, he addressed him as
> Narayana, born on earth to remove the misery of humanity. ....
> Narendra was startled,"What is this I have come to see?" he said to
> himself. "He must be stark mad. Why, I am the son of Viswanath Dutta.
> How dare he speak this way to me?"
>
> ... In answer to Narendra's question, "Sir, have you seen God?" the
> Master said: "Yes, I have seen God. I have seen Him more tangibly than
> I see you. I have talked to Him more intimately than I am talking to
> you." .... Narendra was amazed. These words he could not doubt. This
> was the first time he had ever heard a man saying that he had seen
> God. But he could not reconcile these words of the Master with the
> scene that had taken place on the verandah only a few moments before.
> He concluded that Sri RK was a monomaniac, and returned home rather
> puzzled in mind.
>
> During his second visit, about a month later, **suddenly, at the touch
> of the Master, Narendra felt overwhelmed and saw the walls of the room
> and everything around him whirling and vanishing. "What are you doing
> to me?" he cried in terror. "I have father and mother at home." He saw
> his own ego and the whole universe almost swallowed in a nameless
> void. With a laugh the Master easily restored him.** Narendra thought he
> might have been hypnotized, but he could not understand how a
> monomaniac could cast a spell over the mind of a strong person like
> himself.
>
> But during his third visit Narendra fared no better. This time, **at the
> Master's touch, he lost consciousness entirely**. ....
>
> A few more meetings completely removed from Narendra's mind the last
> traces of the notion that Sri RK might be a monomaniac or wily
> hypnotist. ...
>
> ..Narendra, because of his Brahmo upbringing, considered it wholly
> blasphemous to look on man as one with his Creator. One day at the
> temple garden he laughingly said to a friend: "How silly! This jug is
> God! This cup is God! Whatever we see is God! And we too are God!
> Nothing could be more absurd." **Sri RK came out of his room and gently
> touched him. Spellbound, he immediately perceived that everything in
> the world was indeed God. A new universe opened around him. Returning
> home in a dazed state, he found there too that the food, the plate,
> the eater himself, the people around him, were all God. When he walked
> in the street, he saw that the cabs, the horses, the streams of
> people, the buildings, were all Brahman. ..... It took him a number of
> days to recover his normal self.** He had a foretaste of the great
> experiences yet to come and realized that the words of the Vedanta
> were true.

**The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, Introduction by Swami Nikhilananda**

> In the mean time Vijay had become engaged in conversation with the
> other devotees.
>
> Vijay: “I feel as if someone were always moving
> with me. He shows me what is happening even at a distance.”
> Narendra: “Like a guardian angel.”
>
> Vijay: “I have seen him [meaning Sri Ramakrishna] in Dacca. I even
> touched his body.”
>
> Sri Ramakrishna (with a smile): “It must have been someone else.”
>
> Narendra: “I too have seen him many a time. (To Vijay) How can I say I
> do not believe your words.

**The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, Chapter 46, The Master and Dr. Sarkar, October 25, 1885**

Vijay is the future saint Vijaykrishna Goswami.
Narendra is the future Swami Vivekananda.
Narenda is supporting Vijay’s claim that both have seen Sri Ramakrishna far from Dakshineswar even when he was in Dakshineswar.

Comment: Do you mind participating on the meta site during site elections and raise any concerns you may have on how things are handled on the main site? Some useful links: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2124/what-should-be-on-the-moderator-candidate-questionnaire, https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1993/who-all-are-authority-or-qualified-to-post-an-authoritative-opinion-on-religion, https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1988/is-such-insult-of-rishis-the-authors-of-epics-and-puranas-tolerable, and https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2075.

Comment: Just to clarify it seems everything comes in dreams or awakenings. Meaning no birds, ants, cows or anything else like that?

Answer (score 0):

One arguably supernatural occurrence that fits with the Hindu worldview is the relatively very recent appearance of transmissible cancers.

The ascent of the soul through greater lifeforms should be proof enough of the soul growing in power (the alternative is a God with the contradictory qualities of obsessively caring about human sensibilities, but not other human welfare). However, to clear all doubts, the existence of the many talking animals in Hinduism, who remember their previous lives proofs this without a question. Despite being born as an animal, lower than a human, they often outdo humans, showing their soul's strength makes up for their body's weaknesses. [The dog that speaks before Rama is a good example](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-ramayana-of-valmiki/d/doc424832.html). He is shown as figuring something out that the human ministers of the court did not.

> Hearing the words of the ministers, **Rama said:—•“You do not know the secret of the matter, the dog knows it well!”** Thereafter, questioned by Rama, the dog said:—
>
> ...
>
> In its former birth it had been high-minded but was born in a degraded state in that existence. Repairing to the holy City of Kashi, that dog, desiring to leave its body in a sacred spot, thereafter undertook a waterless fast.

While transmissible cancers appear to not be supernatural, one thing profoundly odd is that they are all very young for immortal beings. Animals have been around 800 million years old as hosts for cancers but the oldest transmissible cancer seems to be CTVT, which is estimated to be only 6000 to 11,000 years old.

[image]

Hinduism can explain the reason for the recent appearance as due to karma in successive lives gradually strengthening a soul, which means as time passes souls would be able to do more impressive things like build a human or turn into a transmissible cancer.

My guess is that all the transmissible cancers are from religious humans that somehow reincarnated in lower organisms before reincarnating again as a transmissible cancer. That's why they are all don't appear before very modern humans (who already had domesticated dogs) and are rare.

P.S. Since the dog story ends in a cliffhanger, with the dog not dying, we can safely assume we will be hearing from him again.

P.P.S Cancers do not forget their previous lives, as I explained [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/49936/21895).

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4698198/

https://naturalhistory.si.edu/education/teaching-resources/life-science/early-life-earth-animal-origins

Comment: Cancers are not supernatural. They are natural as they are part of the material world and not out of the ordinary.

Comment: @Wikash_ Normal cancers are not more supernatural than us. The transmissible cancers are very supernatural. Be it the immortal dog, the recurring, seeking cancers that plague syrian hamsters or HeLa, who always manages to get places where she shouldn't. Also there recent appearance is indicative of their suprenatural nature.