# What are the most documented miracles in Hinduism?

Tags: history, siddhi, evidence, supernatural

By most documented I mean the most supported by evidence, which may include medical records (in the case of a miraculous healing), video recordings (if possible), multiple eyewitnesses, etc. Have there been any notable, well-documented miracles in Hinduism?

A closely related question is [What supernatural things have happened in Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43665/what-supernatural-things-have-happened-in-hinduism), but it lacks the emphasis on documentation that my question has.

Comment: "Miracles" are a Western Christianity phenomena. It is not a part of Eastern religions or philosophy. Hinduism has no pope, no church, no formal organization. Hinduism says have no faith in others, realize God yourself. See God yourself.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda - what do you call it when something happens that defies our current scientific understanding of the laws of Physics?

Comment: One supposed miracle of Sri Raghavendra Swamy, who was a Saint in South India, along with documentation(?) is mentioned here - https://www.indiadivine.org/raghavendra-swami-appeared-british-official-130-years-entering-jeeva-samadhi/

Comment: Like: *"Sun God nourishes all"*? It is documented.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator it is very well documented that Physical world is only part of the whole universe as it fails to encompass existence of aatman (entities beyond physical bodies). Hence hinduism inherently believes and pushes for experiences which are beyond physical boundaries. In fact, aatmic experiences are encouraged over and above physical experiences.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, there have been supernatural humans (pavhari baba who subsisted only on air, and visited by swami vivekananda himself), super-ability humans (vivekananda could recall his past life), super-focused humans (ramakrishna would go into a trance with no external stimulus reaching him), yogis doing levitation after attaining lahima siddhi, making gold shower from sky through prayer (adi shankara, kanakadhara stotram), walking on water (padma pada, sishya of adi shankara), burning a crane with a look (kaushika muni), and innumerable other events that can only be described as miracle

Comment: There is not any. If you find any pls let me know.

Comment: Ramkrishna paramahansa was a miracle

Comment: **First one**. An anecdote of Sir Thomas Munro is told about this place. When Sir Thomas Munro was the Collector of Bellary in 1800, the Madras Government ordered him to procure the annual tax from the Math and Manthralaya village.[11][12] When the Revenue officials were unable to comply with this order,

Comment: Sir Thomas Munro visited the Math for investigation. He removed his hat and shoes and entered the sacred precincts. Sri Raghavendraswamy emerged from the Vrindavan and conversed with him for some time, about the resumption of endowment. The Saint was visible and audible only to Munro, who received Mantraskata (God's blessing).[13] The Collector went back and wrote an order in favour of the Math and the village. This notification was published in the Madras Government Gazette in Chapter XI, page 213, with the caption "Manchali Adoni Taluka". This order is still preserved

Comment: Reference here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sir_Thomas_Munro,_1st_Baronet

Comment: **Second one** The absence of any visual signs of decay in the dead body of Paramahansa Yogananda offers the most extraordinary case in our experience. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paramahansa_Yogananda

Comment: **Third One** Shanti Devi was born in Delhi, India.[1] As a little girl in the 1930s, she began to claim to remember details of a past life. According to these accounts, when she was about four years old, she told her parents that her real home was in Mathura where her husband lived, about 145 km from her home in Delhi. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanti_Devi

Comment: Please collate as answer will vote.. but many time people wanted their answers that is they their micrale like if the questionnairre is devotee of saibaba than they want that as answer that is problem with questionner also. Just my opinion based on my previous answers.. even tough micracles happen every where @MrGreenGold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [Book titled “Living with the Himalayan masters” by Swami Rama](https://archive.org/details/SwamiRamaLivingWithTheHimalayanMasters/page/n36/mode/1up) has lot of those documented miraculous experiences (many includes eye witnesses), lot of people already knows about yogic powers of those Himalayan yogis.

Some miracles to name (you can read more in the book)

**Neem Karoli baba** : who ate arsenic but no poisoning happened. (Pg 38)

**Yogi who throws flame from his mouth** (pg 37)

**[Devraha Baba](https://devrahababa.com/tradition/devrahababa/?lang=en)** : Ageless yogi

> The first president of India dr. Rajendra Prasad witnessed about big age of the yogi. He said that he personally could confirm at least 150 years of his life. At the age of 73 he said that when he was a young boy, his father sent him to meet Baba, who was same old person, and his father had already known Baba for many years before that.
> The presence of Devraha Baba was recorded at 12 main Kumbh Mela holidays which take place once in 12 years.
> The lawyer of Allahabad High Court determined that seven generations of his family had sat at the feet of Devraha Baba.

Comment: Autobiography of a Yogi is full of such experiences